# Grid images showing correctly in Firefox (dev edition) but not in Chrome or Safari

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to do a simple photo gallery with a mosaic layout and it looks exactly as I want it to on Firefox, but when I view it with Chrome or Safari, it's all disproportionate. I've looked around SO and watched some videos on CSS Grid, but I can't find why it would do this. I do notice that when I inspect the grid in Chrome, if I remove the "height: 100%" in my css then it seems to work better but the gap gets messed up too.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong that's making it not work? I'd like to have the Chrome view obviously be the same as the Firefox view. I've included screenshots from each browser as well below.

Here's my code:

```
HTML:
  <div class="mosaic-main">
    <img
      src="GoogleDriveFiles/PhotographyPage/Photo01-320wX240h.JPG"
      alt="clouds at sunset"
      class="col-1-pic pic-1"
    />

    <img
      src="GoogleDriveFiles/PhotographyPage/Photo02-320wX427h.JPG"
      alt="orange tabby cat"
      class="col-2-pic pic-2"
    />

    <img
      src="GoogleDriveFiles/PhotographyPage/Photo03-320wX240h.jpg"
      alt="tree lit up with blue lights"
      class="col-3-pic pic-3"
    />

    <img
      src="GoogleDriveFiles/PhotographyPage/Photo04-320wX240h.jpg"
      alt="darker orange clouds at sunset"
      class="col-1-pic pic-4"
    />

    <img
      src="GoogleDriveFiles/PhotographyPage/Photo05-320wX240h.jpg"
      alt="ambulance driving by with light trails from time lapse"
      class="col-3-pic pic-5"
    />

    <img
      src="GoogleDriveFiles/PhotographyPage/Photo06-320wX240h.jpg"
      alt="black and white gate framing tree without leaves"
      class="col-1-pic pic-6"
    />

    <img
      src="GoogleDriveFiles/PhotographyPage/Photo07-320wX427h.JPG"
      alt="clouds against blue sky"
      class="col-2-pic pic-7"
    />

    <img
      src="GoogleDriveFiles/PhotographyPage/Photo08-320wX240h.jpg"
      alt="storm clouds"
      class="col-3-pic pic-8"
    />

    <img
      src="GoogleDriveFiles/PhotographyPage/Photo09-320wX240H.png"
      alt="black and white pic of orange tabby sleeping on carpet"
      class="col-1-pic pic-9"
    />

    <img
      src="GoogleDriveFiles/PhotographyPage/Photo10-320wX427h.JPG"
      alt="three pink flowers"
      class="col-2-pic pic-10"
    />

    <img
      src="GoogleDriveFiles/PhotographyPage/Photo11-320wX240h.png"
      alt="black and white cat sleeping on a bed"
      class="col-3-pic pic-11"
    />

    <img
      src="GoogleDriveFiles/PhotographyPage/Photo12-320wX240h.png"
      alt="black and white cat sitting on carpet"
      class="col-1-pic pic-12"
    />

    <img
      src="GoogleDriveFiles/PhotographyPage/Photo13-320wX240h.png"
      alt="looking out at raindrops on car window"
      class="col-3-pic pic-13"
    />

    <img
      src="GoogleDriveFiles/PhotographyPage/Photo14-320wX240h.png"
      alt="black and white cat laying on carpet looking at camera"
      class="col-1-pic pic-14"
    />

    <img
      src="GoogleDriveFiles/PhotographyPage/Photo15-320wX427h.jpg"
      alt="black and white cat sitting at glass door"
      class="col-2-pic pic-15"
    />

    <img
      src="GoogleDriveFiles/PhotographyPage/Photo16-320wX240h.png"
      alt="single pink flower against green bush"
      class="col-3-pic pic-16"
    />

    <img
      src="GoogleDriveFiles/PhotographyPage/Photo17-320wX240h.jpg"
      alt="backstage with orange light shining at the end of a dark hallway"
      class="col-1-pic pic-17"
    />

    <img
      src="GoogleDriveFiles/PhotographyPage/Photo18-320wX240h.jpg"
      alt="foggy sunrise looking at city buildings in background"
      class="col-3-pic pic-18"
    />
  </div>

CSS:

.mosaic-main {
  display: grid;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  margin-bottom: 8rem;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(22, 1fr);
}

img {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.col-1-pic {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.col-2-pic {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.col-3-pic {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.pic-1 {
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
}

.pic-2 {
  grid-row: 1 / 6;
}

.pic-3 {
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
}

.pic-4 {
  grid-row: 4 / 7;
}

.pic-5 {
  grid-row: 4 / 7;
}

.pic-6 {
  grid-row: 7 / 10;
}

.pic-7 {
  grid-row: 6 / 11;
}

.pic-8 {
  grid-row: 7 / 10;
}

.pic-9 {
  grid-row: 10 / 13;
}

.pic-10 {
  grid-row: 11 / 16;
}

.pic-11 {
  grid-row: 10 / 13;
}

.pic-12 {
  grid-row: 13 / 16;
}

.pic-13 {
  grid-row: 13 / 16;
}

.pic-14 {
  grid-row: 16 / 19;
}

.pic-15 {
  grid-row: 16 / 22;
}

.pic-16 {
  grid-row: 16 / 19;
}

.pic-17 {
  grid-row: 19 / 22;
}

.pic-18 {
  grid-row: 19 / 22;

}
```

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

[image: Firefox Dev Edition Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Chrome looks like what I expect.**

Because you're forcing `height:100%` I would expect the image to force itself to the grid, which you did not specify a `min-height` for and defined by fraction units.

Mozilla is not retaining the aspect ratio of the images, and defaulting to stretch the images to match the closest grid line, somehow. I didn't test it in Mozilla.

Remove all the `height:100%` references and add this to your CSS:

```
.mosaic-main > img{
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

Comment: Ryan - You are the bomb! It works! Thank you so much. I tried to upvote it but it says because my score is less than 15 (I have an 11 still) it says it records it but doesn't display it.

Still fairly new to this so this is a great format to learn. You are the best. Thanks for helping a newbie!

Comment: You can accept the answer (check mark). That's worth more than an upvote on Stack Overflow. Glad it works for you.

Comment: Done! Thanks a bunch! I have to say it's a great feeling when something starts to work. It's like a natural little high. Lol